# how do I detect that a user has changed google maps from map to satellite

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need to detect when a user changes a map from '**Map**' to '**Satellite**' and vice versa.
There is an event for `'zoom_changed'`
I am trying to find a similar event for changing the view type.

There are some suggestions on stack that using `zoom_changed` might work, but I have tested it, and it doesn't fire on the map type changing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also a event for that called:
`'maptypeid_changed'`

For more information you can look at the [Google Maps Documentation MaptypeId Changed Event](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#Map.maptypeid_changed) and the Property [maptypeid](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#MapTypeId)